# Blackberry JDE v5.0

Tags: blackberry, version, beta, jde

Blackberry JDE v5.0 was released on 03/31/2010. IS that a beta version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior versions all said "beta" on the download page, and it no longer says that - so it's safe to assume that this is the final version.

Answer (score 0):

I have it installed, in "About" written version 5.0.0.25, nothing said about beta, so I think it's not.